# How to wrap text to fit screen in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-wrap

i am kinda new in using d3 as visualization.
Here is my program to visualize document cluster.
[image: the document titles exceed the screen]

the titles of the documents are so long that the screen cannot show the whole titles, so i want to make the title label of each members wrapped.

here is the d3 code:

```
var CodeFlower = function(selector, w, h) {
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;

  d3.select(selector).selectAll("svg").remove();

  this.svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg:svg")
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h);

  this.svg.append("svg:rect")
    .style("stroke", "#6BB6CF")
    .style("fill", "#6BB6CF")
    .attr('width', "615px")
    .attr('height', h);

  this.force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", this.tick.bind(this))
    .charge(function(d) { return d._children ? -d.size / 100 : -40; })
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target._children ? 80 : 25; })
    .size([h, w]);
};

CodeFlower.prototype.update = function(json) {
  if (json) this.json = json;

  this.json.fixed = true;
  this.json.x = this.w / 2;
  this.json.y = this.h / 2;

  var nodes = this.flatten(this.json);
  var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
  var total = nodes.length || 1;

  // remove existing text (will readd it afterwards to be sure it's on top)
  this.svg.selectAll("text").remove();

  // Restart the force layout
  this.force
    .gravity(Math.atan(total / 50) / Math.PI * 0.4)
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

  // Update the links
  this.link = this.svg.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.name; });

  // Enter any new links
  this.link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Exit any old links.
  this.link.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes
  this.node = this.svg.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.name; })
    .classed("collapsed", function(d) { return d._children ? 1 : 0; });

  this.node.transition()
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 3.5 : Math.pow(d.size, 2/5) || 1; });

  // Enter any new nodes
  this.node.enter().append('svg:circle')
    .attr("class", "node")
    .classed('directory', function(d) { return (d._children || d.children) ? 1 : 0; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 3.5 : Math.pow(d.size, 2/5) || 1; })
    .style("fill", function color(d) {
      return "hsl(" + parseInt(360 / total * d.id, 10) + ",90%,70%)";
    })
    .call(this.force.drag)
    .on("click", this.click.bind(this))
    .on("mouseover", this.mouseover.bind(this))
    .on("mouseout", this.mouseout.bind(this));

  // Exit any old nodes
  this.node.exit().remove();

  this.text = this.svg.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'nodetext')
    .attr('dy', 0)
    .attr('dx', 0)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

  return this;
};

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}


CodeFlower.prototype.flatten = function(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) {
      node.size = node.children.reduce(function(p, v) {
        return p + recurse(v);
      }, 0);
    }
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
    return node.size;
  }

  root.size = recurse(root);
  return nodes;
};

CodeFlower.prototype.click = function(d) {
  // Toggle children on click.
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  this.update();
};

CodeFlower.prototype.mouseover = function(d) {
  this.text.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + (d.y - 5 - (d.children ? 3.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 2)) + ')')
    .text(d.name)
    .style('display', null);
};

CodeFlower.prototype.mouseout = function(d) {
  this.text.style('display', 'none');
};

CodeFlower.prototype.tick = function() {
  var h = this.h;
  var w = this.w;
  this.link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  this.node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + Math.max(5, Math.min(w - 5, d.x)) + "," + Math.max(5, Math.min(h - 5, d.y)) + ")";
  });
};

CodeFlower.prototype.cleanup = function() {
  this.update([]);
  this.force.stop();
};
```

i have tried wrapping text function in some sites but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated, many thanks :)

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample data and how one would create your `CodeFlower` object?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Mike Bostock's `wrap` function, you have to call it:

```
var foo = svg.append("text")
    .attr("y", someValue)
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .text("foo bar baz")
    .call(wrap, textWidth);//some value here
```

You can set the y position directly, and the x position using a "transform" (unless you change the "x" attribute of the `<tspan>` inside the `wrap` function).

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("y", 20)
 .attr("dy", 0)
    .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")
 .text("this pure SVG text element is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text indeed.")
 .call(wrap, 280);

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="background-color:wheat"></svg>
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: wrap is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You can use html elements inside SVG to take advantage of automatic line wrapping, provided you set a width and height.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/evs6xsw3/1/

First you need to append a `<foreignObject>` tag into the SVG. Then you can start appending html elements into the `<foreignObject>`, while specifying the html namespace `.append("xhtml:div")`

Comment: Your answer makes the OP believe that you can append HTML elements to an SVG specifying the namespace, which is incorrect. In your snippet you use `foreignObject`, which you don't mention in your answer, and you don't use the namespace you mentioned. Besides that, `foreignObject` will not work on IE. Yet, it was upvoted... go figure it out.